# Jquery datatables plugin not firing after first page of results?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the jquery datatables plugin. I have a number of database rows with non sequential or missing ids : e.g.

```
id   actual row
1     1
2     2
3     3
..
9     9
11    10
```

I have placed a button at the beginning of each row which onclick will grab and send the row to another function for further processing. following the datatables format, the HTML looks like:

```
<table id="myDataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SEND TO</th>
            <th>ROW</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>notes</th>
            .......
    </thead>      
    <tbody>

          <tr id="1">
             <td><button value="1" name="button1">PROCESSING</button></td>   
             <td>1</td>

             <td>1</td>
             .....
```

my javascript looks like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('#myDataTable').dataTable();
                 });


       $(document).ready(function () {

                $('button[name=button1]').click(function(){
                var id= $(this).attr("value");
               console.log(id);
               window.location.href="AjaxController/sendToProcess/"+id;

                });

        });
    </script>
```

Up to row 10 ( id 11 ) everything works as expected. Beyond this The click function does not appear to fire ( nothing is logged to console). I see no errors in the console. Why is this happening and how can I fix it

Comment: you can't have more than one element with the same `id`, [id should be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: changed code as above, no change in result. the first page (first 10 elements ) work. Afterwards none do.

Comment: if the `id` of the row and the `value` of the button are the same then you need to have to specify the `value` attribute, you can use `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are dealing with dynamic elements here because you have a paged table

You need to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[name=button1]', function(){
    var id= $(this).attr("value"); //or $(this).closest('tr').attr('id')
    console.log(id);
    window.location.href="AjaxController/sendToProcess/"+id;

});
```

Comment: Thank you, You fixed it! Would you mind explaining why this happens?

Comment: @user61629 when you use `$('button[name=button1]')` it registers the event handler only to the elements which exists in the dom at that point of time... in your case when the second page is loaded those new buttons does not have the click event handler registered to it